# Run Command to open Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, coded-ui-tests

Is there any Run command to open Notepad++?

Comment: The Run command is not unique to the programming profession, and your question wasn't very serious when you asked it anyway, so it's better off closed. At least you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run, (windows r) then type --> `notepad++.exe`

Comment: Assuming it is on the PATH, however. You might want to go for %PROGRAMFILES%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe in case it is not.

Comment: Okay, try this: `cd\program files\notepad++` then do `notepad++.exe`

Comment: The above comment was meant to be typed in command prompt. So, Run (windows+r), `cmd`, `cd\program files\notepad++`, `notepad++.exe`

Comment: Or you could add an environment variable under System Variables, give the variable the name `npp` and provide the full path to the exe of notepad++.
Then simply type %npp% the first time. From then on, just input the percentile sign, and %npp% would be there in the dropdown list. Select it for your quick needs. Take care though, to not clear that up with CCleaner or the like.